# Removing rows from a dataset based on conditional statement across factors

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, subset

I am struggling to figure out how to remove rows from a dataset based on conditions across multiple factors in a large dataset. Here is some example data to illustrate the problem I am having with a smaller data frame:

```
Code<-c("A","B","C","D","C","D","A","A")
Value<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)

data<-data.frame(cbind(Code, Value))
data$Value <- (as.numeric(data$Value))

data
Code Value
1    A     1
2    B     2
3    C     3
4    D     4
5    C     1
6    D     2
7    A     3
8    A     4
```

I want to remove values where the Code is A and the Value is < 2 from the dataset. I understand the logic of how to select for values where Code  is A and Values <2, but I can't figure out how to remove these values from the dataset without also removing all values of A that are > 2, while maintaining values of the other codes that are less than 2.

```
#Easy to select for values of A less than 2
data2<- subset(data, (Code == "A" & Value < 2))
data2
  Code Value
1    A     1

#But I want to remove values of A less than 2 without also removing values of A that are greater than 2:

data1<- subset(data, (Code != "A" & Value > 2))
data1
  Code Value
3    C     3
4    D     4

### just using Value > 2 does not allow me to include values that are less than 2 for the other Codes (B,C,D):

data2<- subset(data,  Value > 2)
data2
3    C     3
4    D     4
7    A     3
8    A     4
```

My ideal dataset would look like this:

```
data
Code Value
2    B     2
3    C     3
4    D     4
5    C     1
6    D     2
7    A     3
8    A     4
```

I have tried different iterations of filter(), subset(), and select() but I can't figure out the correct conditional statement that allows me to remove the desired combination of levels of multiple factors. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `subset(data, Value > 2)`

Comment: yeah my thoughts exactly.. can you provide a better example @user2096647?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I also want to retain values of the other codes that are less than 2. Using subset (data, Value >2) also eliminates values <2 for these codes. I have updated the question and ideal output accordingly.

Comment: Why was Code 'B' Value '2' removed? Are you looking for something closer to: `subset(data, (Code != "A") | (Code == "A" & Value > 2))`? Sorry if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's exactly what I wanted-I really appreciate it!